# Download and convert Parquet files

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, boto3

I have a vendor who is sharing 1000's of parquet files which I have to download and convert to CSV for my boss to run analysis. But the vendor is not giving ListObjects permission on the AWS S3 bucket. What are my alternatives to get these 1000s of files? I would prefer to get them into my S3 bucket so I can convert them to CSV using spark and then my boss can download CSV later. I am trying to use pyspark with boto3. Below is a snippet of code that I am running on a standalone EC2 instance with Spark.

```
print("starting...")                                                                                                                                                                                     
for s3_file in vendorbucket.objects.filter(Prefix=PREFIX):                                                                                                                                                        
    if 'parquet' in s3_file.key:                                                                                                                                                                                     
        basename, ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.split(s3_file.key)[1])                                                                                                                                          
        print ('processing s3 object= ',s3_file.key)                                                                                                                                                             
        df = spark.read.parquet("s3a://{bucket}/{file}".format(bucket=BUCKET_NAME,file=s3_file.key))                                                                                                             
        df.write.csv("s3a://{bucket}/{file}".format(bucket=OUTPUT_BUCKET_NAME,file=(basename+".csv")))
```

The above code works when I tested with my 2 S3 buckets in my account - one for source and one for output. 
Thanks

Comment: have you any idea about what size have each parquet?...average

Comment: About 200 MB each.